# how to tell what kind of asn1 i'm receiving

Tags: network-programming, network-protocols, asn.1

Im slowly getting my head around asn1 notation. Encoding asn1 from an struct seems to quite easy.However decoding asn1 to my application is harder. I want to know if I have an application that receives data on say udp port 600, and this can be a number of asn1 structures, how do i tell which asn1 structure i should be decoding into?

So, when i receive asn1 packets, do we first determine it's type and the decode it depending on its type?

or does my asn1 compiler handle of this for me?

finding examples of this stuff is hard...even for google ;-) .

A tutorial that outlines the building of simple network server using asn1 would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

ASN.1 corresponds roughly to the [Presentation Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_Layer) of the [OSI seven-layer cake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). It relies on the [Application Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Layer) to determine what types of information is being exchanged between the endpoints. So, there's no universal header or identifier that would indicate **which** protocol or syntax is being presented by the ASN.1 stream. That could be implied by the port number, or made explicit by an additional protocol layer (e.g., HTTP.)

---

**EDIT** (responding to your comment): The [ASN.1 standard](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.680-0207.pdf) defines four "classes" of tags: UNIVERSAL, APPLICATION, PRIVATE, and CONTEXT-SPECIFIC. APPLICATION basically means that the tag is defined for use within a specific application (i.e., it's not pre-defined as part of ASN.1.) But an APPLICATION tag doesn't carry enough information to specify (or even hint at) **which** application is in use.

(Actually, there's very little semantic difference among "APPLICATION", "PRIVATE", and "CONTEXT-SPECIFIC"; these three classes are used mostly for historical and stylistic reasons.)

Comment: so what does [APPLICATION 10] refer to. The protocol i'm dealing with has lots of different requests, on the same udp port... if i run asn1 dump on different packets , I get this header which is different   0  166: [APPLICATION 10] {
   3  163:   SEQUENCE {
   6    3:     [1] {
   8    1:       INTEGER 5
         :       }
  11    3:     [2] {
  13    1:       INTEGER 10
         :       }

Comment: so i presume if i was writing a asn1 decoder, that i'd look at this first , to determine what kind of request i was dealing with.

Comment: @user499211: No, that's not what I said. An ASN.1 message is not required to use APPLICATION tags at all. (Have a look at the grammar at the end of RFC 1157 (http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157.txt) -- not an APPLICATION tag in sight.) If many different kinds of requests can find their way to your decoder, you need some other way to distinguish them. For example, an HTTP header could be used to indicate which kind of request you've got.

Comment: Also have a look at the XML Encoding Rules (XER) for ASN.1: http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.693-0112.pdf In the example on pages 8-9 (by page numberings) of that doc, the XML encoding of the message doesn't carry the class information at all -- no tag is marked as APPLICATION, nor CONTEXT-SPECIFIC, nor UNIVERSAL, nor PRIVATE. That's because these classes really are not very meaningful!

Comment: You could also have one ASN.1 structure for each kind of request, and only accept one generic structure, which is a CHOICE between all your possible request structures.

Comment: @lapo: True -- but only if the developer is the one specifying the ASN.1 formats. user499211's question seems to imply that someone else has designed the ASN.1 packets.